# Message UI changing with Xcode

Tags: sms, xcode5

Im currently making an app that involves the message UI with Xcode 5. To keep things short I want to be able to compile the text, but when I hit send I don't want it to send, I want to change what that button does. Any help?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Is it that you want to take the content from [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and do something *else* with it other than send a SMS?

Comment: When I bring up the MessageUI While running the app, when I tap send it sends the message. What I want to do is change what tapping the send button does, like bring up a new view controller or something.